# Convert a Tree Class into a simpler Tree class and Serialize to Json maintaining structure

Tags: c#, json, tree, json.net

ok, so i have a class similar to this:

```
public class Channel
{
    public Guid Guid{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}

    /* GOT A LOT MORE PROPERTIES IN THIS SPACE */

    public Guid Parent {get;set;}
    public List<Channel> Children{get;set;}
}
```

i also have a `List<Channels>` (with a total of about 650 `Channels`)

the `ROOT` channel contains about 6 channels and each of the channels contains, children and so on.

as you see in the code of `Channel` there are a lot of other properties,
which i don't want to serialize IN THIS CASE. that is, all the `Data Contracts` are already defined in the base class, and i do not/can not change them just for this action.

so, what is my problem you ask?
i need to get a `List<Channels>` or `List<NewType>` to be serialized to `JSON` and maintain the Tree structure.

if it is not possible, at least, how would i serialize the `List<Channels>` to `JSON` maintaining the structure?

**EDIT:**
i am using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: Have you considered serializing the list to an array of type Channel?

Comment: that gives me a flat array, while i need to keep the structure.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It maintans an array of the Channel structure...is this not what you are asking?

Comment: Is this the question you were talking about? I'm not a NewtonSoft programmer, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would suggest serializing the list to an array of Channels...consider the following JSON example:

```
{
    "Channel": {
        "Guid": "27182d04-29d9-4760-86d5-484ba43cd9c6",
        "Title": "FooBar",
        "Parent": "52cfd532-6010-41c5-8fa9-f3bcbb97a630",
        "Children": [
            {
                "Channel": {
                    "Guid": "27182d04-29d9-4760-86d5-484ba43cd9c6",
                    "Title": "FooBar",
                    "Parent": "52cfd532-6010-41c5-8fa9-f3bcbb97a630",
                    "Children": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Channel": {
                    "Guid": "27182d04-29d9-4760-86d5-484ba43cd9c6",
                    "Title": "FooBar",
                    "Parent": "52cfd532-6010-41c5-8fa9-f3bcbb97a630",
                    "Children": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Channel": {
                    "Guid": "27182d04-29d9-4760-86d5-484ba43cd9c6",
                    "Title": "FooBar",
                    "Parent": "52cfd532-6010-41c5-8fa9-f3bcbb97a630",
                    "Children": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Here is a little test code which will write this structure:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace JSONTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Channel c = new Channel();
            c.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            c.Parent = Guid.NewGuid();
            c.Title = "FooBar";
            c.Children = new List<Channel>();

            Channel a = new Channel();
            Channel b = new Channel();

            a.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            b.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();

            a.Parent = Guid.NewGuid();
            b.Parent = Guid.NewGuid();

            a.Title = "FooBar_A";
            b.Title = "FooBar_B";

            c.Children.Add(a);
            c.Children.Add(b);

            /* Serialization happens here!! */
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string result = serializer.Serialize(c);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Channel
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        /* GOT A LOT MORE PROPERTIES IN THIS SPACE */

        public Guid Parent { get; set; }
        public List<Channel> Children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the result of that test after being passed through JSONLint

```
{
    "Guid": "0e72c12c-a7a1-461a-8b84-8b17023e2e2f",
    "Title": "FooBar",
    "Parent": "d0943246-1adc-4208-bb3b-1249ffe5e7b4",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Guid": "1cf413be-d6b5-405e-8308-7c6dfe817f9a",
            "Title": "FooBar_A",
            "Parent": "ecf14fce-c97d-46f5-890b-bab8ff99fb4a",
            "Children": null
        },
        {
            "Guid": "bd96e6d3-f247-4a0d-9147-92da19793e97",
            "Title": "FooBar_B",
            "Parent": "5cd3e765-23c2-4145-8b45-9964a7c66c54",
            "Children": null
        }
    ]
}
```

VALID JSON!

EDIT: One thing I have noticed is that JavaScriptSerializer does not parse "Channel", since the whole object is of type Channel and each object in "Children" is of type Channel. If you were to pass this JSON through the Deserialize method, if should build this back into a C# structure with all JSON persisted data.

Comment: Could you show some code to achieve that? this is what i am trying to do, but i do not know how to do it...

Comment: @Dementic, sure...take another look at my answer!

Comment: @Dementic, I have noticed you have edited to say you are using Newtonsoft.JSON...I have written my example using Microsoft's built in JSON Serializer. If Microsoft's serializer can do it, I'm sure Newtonsoft's serializer can do it also!...however I have no experience with JSON.NET as I have built my own, personal JSON serializer/deserializer

Comment: this is great, but, my original `Children` for a channel has the ` [XmlIgnore]` attribute, which i cannot change.

Comment: @Dementic...I'm not sure why [XmlIgnore] would be picked up by a JSON serializer as XML and JSON are different formats?...let me check

Comment: also, i am getting `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Channels+Channel'.` with your code.

Comment: @Dementic, certainly with the Microsoft JavaScriptSerializer class, XmlIgnore...is ignored, presumably becuase XML isn't JSON! ;-)

Comment: @Dementic, I also got a circular reference when I said c.Children.Add(c);...this MUST NOT happen. All child instances must me unique, and MUST NOT reference the parent!

Comment: you are asking the impossible. since `Parent` is part of the `Channel` class.

Comment: @Dementic, NO, sorry there is confusion here...I do not mean the Parent property, I mean "Parent" as in the object which holds the Child and Parent properties. E.G. Channel X (X is the parent). if I say X.Child.Add(X), X (the parent object), is being referenced as a child of itself...this is what causes the circular reference

Comment: There is no way it is happening. btw, i did removed the `Parent` property for a test (since i can still use `ParentChannelGuid`) and the Circular reference disappeared.