# Using JSON.Net to extract a generic tree structure from instances of my classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm creating an add-in for a 3rd party piece of software which exports data from the native files to JSON. For this I'm developing a series of C#.NET classes which represent the data I want to export. My tool generates instances of these classes from data in the software and then serializes these instances to JSON using JSON.NET.

For example I might have classes like the following....

```
public class Document
{
    public string FileName {get; set;}
    public string FileSize {get; set;}
    public List<Bar> Bars  {get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Bar> SubBars {get; set;}
}
```

..which get serialized into...

```
{
  "FileName": "foobar.abc",
  "FileSize": 12345,
  "Bars": [
    {
      "Name": "Bar 1",
      "SubBars": []
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bar 2",
      "SubBars": [
        {
          "Name": "Bar 2a",
          "SubBars": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "Bar 2b",
          "SubBars": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This all works fine. However, I also want to show the exported data hierarchy in a tree control, and thus need a generic way to get the "children" of any of my classes.

My first thought was to create an interface for all my classes to implement which would return a dictionary of values.

```
public interface IItem
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> GetValues();
}
```

A implementation of this may look like the following..

```
public class Document:IItem
{
    public string FileName {get; set;}
    public string FileSize {get; set;}
    public List<Bar> Bars  {get; set;}

    public IDictionary<string, object> GetValues()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>(); 
        dict.Add("FileName", FileName);
        dict.Add("FileSize ", FileSize);
        dict.Add("Bars", Bars);
        return dict;
    }
}
```

This would be tedious to update if I add, remove, or rename properties of my classes. Alternatively, I could create a default implementation of this interface which uses reflection to return the properties of my classes.

```
public class Item:IItem
{ 
    public IDictionary<string, object> GetValues()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();             
        //Code that adds all properties to the dictionary
        //through reflection goes here....
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Yet this duplicates the reflection logic already built into JSON.Net, and most likely will become more complicated then I would like. For example if I add the [JsonIgnore] attributes to properties of my classes I would need to take this into account. I wouldn't want these values displayed in my tree control if they were not being saved to the JSON.

Is there some way I can use JSON.Net to determine the same generic tree structure from my class instances or serialized JSON? I've used XML and the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class in my previous projects, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding class in JSON.Net which represents a generic JSON document.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow what you're trying to do. What's the problem with the tree structure you already have?

Comment: Maybe you could try `Jobject,Parse(json)` instead of `JsonConvert`: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: Have you looked at `JObject` or `JArray`.

Comment: What kind of tree control are you using?  If you're using WPF, you could serialize to a `JObject` and do something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812357/how-to-bind-dynamic-json-into-treeview-wpf.

Comment: JObject.FromObject() seems to be what I was looking for, can some one post an actual answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232306/convert-a-tree-class-into-a-simpler-tree-class-and-serialize-to-json-maintaining
Might be helpfull